# Sketch: disable pixel-snapping when resizing elements

Tags: vector, sketch-app, resize

When I resize a vector to a very small size, it comes out looking distorded due to Sketch not allowing for sub-pixels (if that's how they word it...) — see below example:

[image]

Notice that the above instagram logo looks wrong due to me making it very small.

Is there a way around this? I read the following answer on another question on here:

> Go to sketch > preferences (on a mac press cmd + ,), and under the
> first tab (General), uncheck the first box (says "pixel fitting: Fit
> layers and points to pixel bounds").

But I dont have that as an option under Preferences, I imagine it's been removed from more recent versions of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end, I had to disable the following:

[image]